# Refer to nodes by variable index number

Tags: xml, xslt, text

I need to build a flat table in text from a hierarchical XML. I need one flat line per `meas` node. Each `meas` node has an index number (`mN`), which refers back to a smaller section which where a label (`tL`) is kept for each unique possibility of the index number. I want to loop each `meas` node and use the value of `mN` attribute to look up the corresponding `tL` value. The example below delivers the index (`mN`) numbers properly, but always delivers `One` for every row:

**xml**

```
<root>
    <cond tN="1" tL="One"/>
    <cond tN="2" tL="Two"/>
    <cond tN="3" tL="Three"/>
    <cond tN="4" tL="Four"/>
    <cond tN="5" tL="Five"/>
    <meas mN="1"/>
    <meas mN="2"/>
    <meas mN="3"/>
    <meas mN="4"/>
    <meas mN="5"/>
    <meas mN="1"/>
    <meas mN="2"/>
    <meas mN="3"/>
    <meas mN="4"/>
    <meas mN="5"/>
</root>
```

**xsl**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/meas">
            <xsl:variable name="MeasN">
                <xsl:value-of select="@mN"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$MeasN"/>,
            <xsl:value-of select="../cond[$MeasN]/@tL"/>.
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

> ```
> 1 One
> 2 One
> 3 One
> 4 One
> 5 One
> 1 One
> 2 One
> 3 One
> 4 One
> 5 One
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MeasN` contains a string, which means your expression `cond[$MeasN]` will find all `cond` elements for which your string is non-empty (i.e all of them). However, `xsl:value-of` will then just output the first.

You probably need to do this

```
 <xsl:value-of select="../cond[number($MeasN)]/@tL"/>
```

Or maybe, you should be you should be checking the `tN` attribute instead? (This would work regardless of the order of the `cond` elements

```
 <xsl:value-of select="../cond[@tN = $MeasN]/@tL"/>
```

In the case of checking the `tL` attribute, instead of the position, you could also achieve it with a key...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="cond" match="cond" use="@tN" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/meas">
            <xsl:variable name="MeasN" select="@mN"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$MeasN"/>,
            <xsl:value-of select="key('cond', $MeasN)/@tL"/>.
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tim C, thank you very much! All of your suggestions are suitable and give me plenty to work with and learn from. And, thanks for simplifying my xsl:variable.